# A more recent version of _catalogs/masterpage... has been saved by Test_User on 4-20-2015. page not saved

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have edited my **Master Page** and trying to save it but a message shown by this dialog box. But this file is not replacing my updated code.
please ignore my bad English 
[image]

Comment: If you click 'yes' your master page is not replace? check at http://yoursite/_catalogs/masterpage/forms/allitems.aspx if the page is edited

Comment: every time i renamed file to save